# Develop for Android 5.1 on Delphi 10.4?

Tags: android-5.1.1-lollipop, delphi-10.4-sydney

I am using Delphi 10.4 to develop for Android. I have a Motorola XT1060 running Android 5.1 that is compatible with Delphi 10.3 but generates a OLDER_SDK error on Delphi 10.4. The Android Syscheck utility results suggest the phone should meet the requirements for 10.4 described in the 10.4 docs.

The Andorid SDK Manager show Android SDK 25.2.5 32-bit in both the 10.3 and 10.4 installations. But the SDK base path and SDK API-Level location both differ between 10.3 and 10.4. I have not compared the NDK settings.

My question is whether I can safely set the 10.4 SDK settings to the 10.3 values, ie point 10.4 to the locations used by 10.3.  I don't want to create some subtle problem that will bite me down the line if the reconfiguration appears to work.

More broadly, is there a way I can develop for the XT1060 with Delphi 10.4 or do I need to go back to 10.3?

Thanks

Comment: I tried adding the 10.3 SDK to 10.4 but since they have the same name that wasn't allowed. I didn't try renaming the 10.3 SDK.

Comment: I found that the 10.3 AndroidManifest.xml file sets minSdkVersion = 19 and targetSdkVersion = 28. This could translate to a  range of compatibility of Android 4.4 to Android 9 (except the 10.3 docs specify Android 5 as the lower limit). The same file in 10.4 sets these values to, 23 and 29, suggesting a compatibility range of Android 6 to Android10. I don't know if these conclusions are correct but they were enough to convince me to drop support for Android 5 from my project spec.

Answer (score 1):

You probably would need to go back to 10.3. I just ran into this issue today with 10.4 and it not working on 5.1.1. [The Docwiki](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Android_Devices_Supported_for_Application_Development) claims greater than 5.0 should work, but appears wrong.